# True or false as a result and why

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement

If I have one piece of code:

```
public boolean login(String username, String pass) throws SQLException{
Connection conn = connect();
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from users where ime = ? and sifra = ?");
st.setString(1, username);
st.setString(2, pass);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
return rs.next();
}
```

and another

```
if(login(creds[0], creds[1]))
```

Why is result of "if" statement true or false. I know that is true or false but i can't understand it why. I am missing some brain information. Can someone chew it for me step by step?

Comment: Because `login()` returns a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `login` method returns a `boolean`, which can only be true or false. Take a look at the last line of that method:

```
return rs.next();
```

Notice how you are returning the resulting value of calling `next()` on `rs`? From your code, `rs` is a `ResultSet`. You can take a look at the [java api docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) To find that `next()` returns

> true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows

Comment: Yes, but i can't still understand why it is true or false.
With st.setstring 1 & 2 i put method input strings in sql query and set the result of that query in variable "rs".
Does it mean that if i succeed to DO that query, to set it to pass, to not break a program, does it mean that i go to next line which is in this situation rs.nextline and that is ok for program and he will say: "Ok you passed with that query, i am still alive and i will return true because everything is ok"?

Comment: @dowlabordere When you execute your query, you store it into a ResultSet. If you take a look at the link from my answer, you'll see "A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on." This means that by calling `next`, you are telling the cursor to try to retrieve the first result. If there are no more results, `next` will return false. So your `login` method is essentially checking that there is at least 1 result from your query.